# Referencing an element without including/importing the schemaLocation in which it is defined

Tags: xsd

I have two xsd files. 1st file is `common.xsd` and the other is `node.xsd`. Both `node.xsd` and `common.xsd` share the same `targetNamespace`. `common.xsd` references an `element` defined in `node.xsd` using `ref` attribute. However, `node.xsd` is NOT included in `common.xsd` either using `include` or `import`. But the XML that I validate using these xsd files, passes the validation (Tried all corner usecases).

I wonder how this is possible. Is this because, they share the same namespace? Also is referencing an `element` without including/importing legal in XSD?

**EDIT:**

Simplified Code Snippets(The actual xsd's are much more complex and they are written in this format for bigger reason):

common.xsd

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:my="my-namespace"
        xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"
        targetNamespace="my-namespace"
        elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xsd:element name="common" type="my:commonType" />
  <xsd:complexType name="commonType">
    <xsd:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xsd:element ref="my:node"/>
      <!-- few other elements -->
    </xsd:choice>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

node.xsd

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:my="my-namespace"
        xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"
        targetNamespace="my-namespace"
        elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xsd:include schemaLocation=common.xsd"/>
  <xsd:element name="node" type="my:nodeType"
           substitutionGroup="my:common" />
  <xsd:complexType name="nodeType">
    <xsd:complexContent>
      <xsd:extension base="my:commonType">
        <!-- some 5-7 attributes -->
        <xsd:anyAttribute/>
      </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

These xsd's let me nest  element within itself any number of times.
E.g

```
<my:node>
  <my:node />
  <my:node>
    <my:node />
  </my:node>
</my:node>
```

You can observe that `my:node` is referenced in `common.xsd` without including `node.xsd`. (Curious as to how this even works.)

Comment: Can you show the code how u r validating the XML?

Comment: Arjun, which tool are you using to validate your instance document?

Comment: I'm using JDeveloper. It shows that XML is valid as per the schema. It also shows that my `common.xsd` file is referring to undefined element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can make this look even more wicked... You can remove the `xsd:include` in `node.xsd` and still validate your XML! Take a look at this [Xerces API](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/javadocs/xerces2/org/apache/xerces/jaxp/validation/XMLSchemaFactory.html#newSchema%28javax.xml.transform.Source%5B%5D%29) for how you could do it.

The idea is that from a spec perspective, an XML Schema processor can resolve schema locations in many ways. It also means that some XSD files when looked at individually may not be valid due to dangling references, yet when put **together** through APIs like the one above, or custom resolvers (e.g. supporting "catalog" files) the result is an **equivalent** schema that is valid.

The way an XSD processor typically works, is that it puts together all the schema components that can be loaded through the references it can resolve, then it looks at the result as a whole, irrespective of where these components come from.  In your case, **node.xsd** brings in **common.xsd**; the result is a valid schema, since all that is needed for components in `common.xsd` can be found among components already brought in by `node.xsd`.

In your case it is as if the inner content of the xsd:schema tag in `common.xsd` replaces the `xsd:include` in `node.xsd`. If you do that by hand, the result is correct, right?

As I side note, I would point out that the snippets you've shown don't illustrate the use of the `common` substitution group. As a reminder, you have to reference **the head** of the substitution group if you want you to get substitution going.

Comment: Thanks! That clears a lot of things.

And yeah, common.xsd & node.xsd share some attributes which is why it is being used as substitution group. Missed that out while creating simple schema